# Dynamic ffill using another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date':['01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/04/2019','01/05/2019','01/06/2019','01/07/2019','01/08/2019','01/09/2019','01/10/2019],
'flag':['start',np.nan,np.nan,'end','end','end','start',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'days':[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
})
```

i want to ffill df['flag'] based on 'days' so the resulting df looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date':['01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/04/2019','01/05/2019','01/06/2019','01/07/2019','01/08/2019','01/09/2019','01/10/2019],
'flag':['start','start',np.nan,'end','end','end','start','start','start',np.nan],
'days':[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
})
```

and i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: `df.groupby('day').ffill()`?

Comment: Why is not replaced last `NaN` per group?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need:

```
df['flag'] = df['flag'].mask(df['days'].isna(), df['flag'].ffill())
print (df)
         date   flag  days
0  01/01/2019  start   1.0
1  01/02/2019  start   NaN
2  01/03/2019  start   NaN
3  01/04/2019    end   NaN
4  01/05/2019    end   NaN
5  01/06/2019    end   NaN
6  01/07/2019  start   NaN
7  01/08/2019    NaN   2.0
8  01/09/2019  start   NaN
9  01/10/2019  start   NaN
```

Comment: tried this, doesn't give the expected output since the `start` is shifted.

Comment: @QuangHoang - For me unclear, so ask comment under question.

Comment: wouldnt this just ffill 'days' too far, and as a result, 'flag' gets ffilled too far?

Comment: @diehard - Unfortunately not understand what need, because seems there is some shift of data, some NaNs are not replace. Can you explian more logic for forward filling days?

Comment: i need to ffill the 'flag' column by the number of days in 'days'. if there is a null in 'days' , i do not want anything ffill'd.

Comment: @diehard - Answer is edited, but still not sure if understand

Comment: oh boy i messed up my original df, when there is always a corresponding 'days' entry on the first occurrence of 'start' . how does that change your solution?